# копировать элемент массива не используя метод System.arraycopy()?

Tags: java

Практики не бывает много, а тем более, когда речь идет об операциях над массивами! А у нас тут завалялось несколько массивов со случайными числами, как раз поможешь нам их немного подчистить. Создай метод `getDivisibleNumbers()`, который будет принимать два параметра: входной массив `int [] numbers` и `int divider`. А возвращать результирующий массив только с теми числами, которые нацело делятся на `int divider` и является положительными.

Пример: С такими входными данными:

```java
int [] numbers = {2, 5, 8, 0, 7, 1, -4};
int divider = 2;
```

ожидаемый результат:

```
int [] result = {2, 8};
```

Я так понял что алгоритм такой:

1. проверить как делится элемент массива
2. создать промежуточный массив равен длинной исходному массиву numbers
3. присвоить результат деления в промежуточный массив
4. тут я не  знаю надо либо по удалять в промежуточном массиве те ячейки которые не заполненны и тогда он же станет результатирующим массивом либо взять элементы из этого промежуточного массива и переписать в результатирующий массив который надо создать отдельно но в таком случае как прописать его длину?

Answer (score 2):

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = {2, 5, 8, 0, 7, 1, -4};
        int divider = 2;

        int[] array = getDivisibleNumbers(numbers, divider);
        IntStream.of(array).forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static int[] getDivisibleNumbers(int[] array, int devider) {
        return IntStream.of(array)
                .filter(i -> i > 0)
                .filter(i -> i % devider == 0)
                .toArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: только одно замечание... Разве 0 не делится нацело на 2? 0 вроде входит в множество целых чисел...

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець "которые нацело делятся на int divider и является положительными"

Answer (score 0):

Если [функциональное решение с использованием Java Stream API](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1331890/386633) по какой-либо причине не приемлемо, можно использовать другой алгоритм:

- на первом проходе определить количество элементов во входном массиве, удовлетворяющих условию
- создать результирующий массив нового размера
- скопировать в него все подходящие элементы из входного массива, пока результирующий массив не будет заполнен.

```java
static int[] getDivisibleNumbers(int[] arr, int divider) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > 0 && arr[i] % divider == 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    int[] result = new int[count];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < arr.length && j < count; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > 0 && arr[i] % divider == 0) {
            result[j++] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```